# "mozilla crash reporter" cannot be disabled

Tags: firefox, crash

I get the popup like every few hours, so annoying. So I googled and followed the how-to ( [Disable Mozilla Crash Reporter in Firefox [Updated]](https://techdows.com/2010/01/disabling-mozilla-crash-reporter-in.html) ) for disabling the reporting feature, but it doesn't work (still I get those popups).

[image]

Note: From the article what I've done is basically: For `\Firefox Developer Edition\application.ini`
and `\Mozilla Firefox\application.ini`:

```
// ..
[Crash Reporter]
Enabled=0
```

Also note that I'm not opening any Firefox instance for days. It's very weird and suspicious that Firefox is doing something shady in background, running no (apparently) Firefox (related) process.

I'm used to using Firefox Dev, so uninstalling is the final resort. So, how to fix the issue? Thanks.

Comment: try rename associated exe perhaps?

Comment: You can always check the details yourself, without sending them to Mozilla. And then perhaps resolve the crash cause. // It's possible that beta versions of Firefox cannot have the Crash Reporter disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article
[Mozilla Crash Reporter](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Mozilla_Crash_Reporter)
has this text with several possible solutions.

> **Can I disable Crash Reporter?**
>
> Mozilla Crash Reporter is enabled by default and there is no user
> interface to disable it. Advanced users who prefer the standard
> application error notifications (e.g., the Windows error dialog
> " has encountered a problem and needs to close" and Event
> Viewer record) can disable the Mozilla Crash Reporter by adding a
> system environment variable named **MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_DISABLE** and
> setting its value to 1.
>
> Note: Another method to disable the Mozilla Crash Reporter was to open
> the "application.ini" file in the installation directory, find the
> entry **[Crash Reporter] Enabled=1** and change the 1 to 0 (repeating
> the edit if an application update replaces the file) but this may no
> longer work since the fix for bug 686466.
>
> Note: Unchecking the "Submit crash reports" option/preference (e.g.,
> in Firefox Options -> Advanced / General (tab), under "System
> Defaults") does not turn off the Crash Reporter; it simply toggles the
> default of the "Tell Mozilla about this crash so they can fix it"
> check box in the Mozilla Crash Reporter dialog (upon crash). On
> Windows XP you need to modify the registry; otherwise, this setting is
> not saved and the "Submit crash reports" option will again be checked
> when you next restart your Mozilla application. The value
> **SubmitCrashReport** needs to be set in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Crash Reporter** for all users and **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Crash
> Reporter** for a single user. When the DWORD value of
> **SubmitCrashReport** is 0, the Crash Report will not be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the environment variable solution, as advised on the comment, the file renaming way seems to be working fine so far for me.

So,

```
C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\crashreporter.exe
```

to e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\_crashreporter.exe
```

Knowing that the `application.ini` way is no longer supported, you could say it's likely the `MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_DISABLE` way also might be deprecated in the near future. So, perhaps this simple workaround might worth be noted.